# InnoSetup uninstaller UAC from Apps&Features

Tags: windows, windows-10, inno-setup, uninstallation, uac

I'm using InnoSetup to create an installer for my programm.
This is installed without admin privileges to (per default: "AppData\Local\Programs\MyApp") if i double click the **unins000.exe** in there, it works out of the box without UAC prompt.

In the Windows 10 metro-style System Settings → Apps&Features trying to uninstall MyApp asks for administrator privileges.

Doing the same in the old-school "Programms and Features" (appwiz.cpl) clicking uninstall everything works fine.

My question is:

Why does Apps&Features require more privileges, and how do I turn this off?

Comment: It seems that this is a design flaw in the Windows 10 uninstall tool (as you noted, uninstalling from `Programs and Features` doesn't exhibit this problem). As far as I know, there's no way around this problem other than use `Programs and Features` or run the uninstaller executable directly.